# Вывод всех данных 2 связанных таблиц ruby

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть две модели, связь один ко многим. Первая модель "категории", вторая модель задачи.
У категорий много задач, у задачи одна категория. Нужно вывести все данные таблицы. Те сначала категория, под ней все задачи. Как это сделать?

Модель категории:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :todos
end
```

Модель задачи:

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :projects, class_name: "Project"
end
```

Экшн обработки

```
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end
```

Вывод всех категорий

```
<ul>
    <% @projects.each do |project|%>
    <li>
        <%=project.title%>      
        </li>
     <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте в `index`

```
@projects = Project.includes(:todos)
```

а в представлении

```
...
<%=project.title%> 
<% project.todos.each do |todo| %>
  <%= todo.some_attr %>
<% end %>
...
```